# Xamarin form authentication with azure active directory using xamarin.oauth

Tags: authentication, xamarin, oauth, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement authentication in xamarin forms using xamarin.auth library with azure AD. I have registered my app as api in AD and getting the app id from there. From where i will get redirect URI for my app? when i am trying with redirect url given in registered app, it is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for it. Thought of posting if it can help anyone.

There is custom URI scheme for native apps where you can assign a url to your app. For iOS app using xamarin form we can assign the custom uri for the app in info.plist and use the same uri as redirect URL in azure AD app registration.